# function leading to java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: scala

```
  def move(s: String) { 
    var moveList: List[Char] = s.toList
    moveList.foreach(moveList(_) match {
      case 'r' => ar()
      case 'l' => al()
      case 'u' => au()
      case 'd' => ad()
    })
  }
```

my current function leads to the error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 114. If you could please help it would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moveList.foreach(moveList(_)` this is the same as `moveList(char => moveList.apply(char.toInt))` that should give you an idea of what is wrong.

In any case, the point of a `foreach` is to take *each* element of the collection and apply that function to *each* of them. That is why the name FOR EACH. Not to access the elements by some index.
Also, a **String** is already an iterable, thus your code can be simplified to:

```
def move(s: String): Unit =
  s.foreach {
    case 'r' => ar()
    case 'l' => al()
    case 'u' => au()
    case 'd' => ad()
    case c   => println(s"Bad action: ${c}")
  }
```

PS: Try to avoid **vars**, especially useless ones.
Force yourself to use **vals** everywhere.

Comment: Thanks! you helped me out a lot, and il take your advice